# reading character arrays from a file to another array in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a text file which consists of different combinations of characters. For example:

```
a+b*c
b+c*a
c+a*b
```

I want to read this file into matlab, and want to assign each line to an array like this:

```
c(1)=a+b*c
c(2)=b+c*a
c(3)=c+a*b
```

Further, I would like to assign other character arrays to the variables a,b,c etc. For example, I can assign as

```
a='A', b='B', c='C'
```

and print the final outputs as:

```
c(3)=C+A*B
```

But I am stuck at both the steps, as to how to read and assign the different lines to different character arrays in Matlab. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `c(3)=C+A*B` or as a string like this ? -`c(3)='C+A*B'`

Comment: yes, like a string! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) to read the text into a cell array and perform the replacements one by one.

**Code**

```
%%// Name of your text file
file1 = 'eqns.txt'

c = importdata(file1)

c = strrep(c,'a','A');
c = strrep(c,'b','B');
c = strrep(c,'c','C')
```

**Output**

```
c = 
    'a+b*c'
    'b+c*a'
    'c+a*b'

c = 
    'A+B*C'
    'B+C*A'
    'C+A*B'
```

If you are interested in getting the alphabets into upper-case, you can directly do so after importing data -

```
c = importdata(file1)
c = upper(c)
```